# Processing "live" data in background and smooth refreshing Java JPanel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, audio, smoothing

I'm trying to make a program in Java, that reading audio file, processing it and showing on diagrams etc.

I was reading a lot about Multithreading and Concurency in Swing but I don't find out solution to my problem.

I'm reading audio file, making on it some calculations (like FFT) and I want to showing it on my JPanel. I'm also reading a few seconds forward to get what i want. And I'm doing it in background. The current result of my calc (current part of music) is on my JPanel extended class.

I don't want to write there all of my code, so i make a example of my problem by using sound getting from microfone.

My classes:

**startClass**

```
package bobstang.mv.tests.swingtest;

import javax.swing.*;

public class startClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**GUI**

```
package bobstang.mv.tests.swingtest;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUI {

    JFrame mainFrame;
    PaintPanel panel;

    boolean isWorking;

    SwingWorker<Void, Record> worker;

    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;

    public GUI() {
        Mixer.Info[] mi = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo =
                new DataLine.Info(
                        TargetDataLine.class,
                        audioFormat);

        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mi[0]);
        System.out.println("Selected mic: " + mi[0]);

        //Get a TargetDataLine on the selected
        // mixer.
        try {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            //Prepare the line for use.
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            targetDataLine.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Record>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                int len = 0;
                while(len != -1) {
                    byte[] buffor = new byte[600];
                    len = targetDataLine.read(buffor, 0, buffor.length);
                    System.out.println("Publishing");
                    publish(new Record(buffor, audioFormat));
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Record> chunks) {
                super.process(chunks);
                for(Record r : chunks) {
                    System.out.println("panel.settingRecord");
                    panel.setRecord(r);
                    //panel.repaint();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                super.done();
                System.out.println("end of reading mic");
            }
        };

        mainFrame = new JFrame("TEST");

        panel = new PaintPanel();

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                start();
            }
        });

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, startButton);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(16, panel);
        timer.start();
        worker.execute();
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
        float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
        //8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        //8,16
        int channels = 1;
        //1,2
        boolean signed = true;
        //true,false
        boolean bigEndian = false;
        //true,false
        return new AudioFormat(
                sampleRate,
                sampleSizeInBits,
                channels,
                signed,
                bigEndian);
    }//end getAudioFormat
}
```

**paintClass**

```
package bobstang.mv.tests.swingtest;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int height = 500;
    private int width = 800;

    int progres = 0;

    Record record;

    public PaintPanel() {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    public void setRecord(Record r) {
        record = r;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("paintComponet()");

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        int y0 = getHeight()/2;
        g.fillRect(0,0,progres,5);
        progres++;

        while(record != null) {
            int len = record.getAudioData()[0].length;
            double[] data = record.getAudioData()[0];

            int border = (getWidth() - len)/2;
            if(border < 0)
                border=0;

            for(int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
                int y = (int)(data[i]*y0);
                g.fillRect(border+i, y0+y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("actionPerformed()");
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and **Record**

```
package bobstang.mv.tests.swingtest;

import bobstang.mv.audio.AudioReader;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;

public class Record {

    private byte[] byteData;

    private double[][] audioData;

    public Record(byte[] byteData, AudioFormat audioFormat) {
        this.byteData = byteData;
        audioData = AudioReader.getAudioData(byteData, audioFormat);
    }

    public byte[] getByteData() {
        return byteData;
    }

    public double[][] getAudioData() {
        return audioData;
    }

}
```

What I want to get is to showing mic input as a waveform on my JPanel.
And make it smooth.

How to make it good? JPanel should showing "output of my job" 60Hz and in background are making other calculations needed (2sec of audio forward).

Comment: Check out SwingWorker

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But while SwingWorker is publishing/processing data, Timer don't works properly :/ And also if I'm calling repaint() from SwingWorker it don't works.